# mssql ssl encryption jdbc connection prolem with openjdk11

Tags: sql-server, ssl

I am running a java app with mssql client on openjdk11 to connect msssql server. I got below ssl encrypting problem

My assumption is the mssql server using a wrong certificate which's root CA is not in my java's default truststore.
My question is why connection is ssl encrypted altough jdbc url does not set to use ssl?

Any suggestion or hints?

jdbc url setting

```
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://110.169.133.256:1433;databaseName=TEST_DEV
```

Error stacktrace is like below

```
: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints". ClientConnectionId:938c1bcb-8e88-46d9-9776-379716c39369
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:82)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:646)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:685)
        at io.neptune.camel.component.sql.ext.SqlExtProducer.process(SqlExtProducer.java:150)
        at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:66)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:169)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$SimpleTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:395)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleSync(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:65)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.process(MulticastProcessor.java:290)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Splitter.process(Splitter.java:145)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.process(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:83)
        at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorSupport.process(AsyncProcessorSupport.java:41)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:286)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline$PipelineTask.run(Pipeline.java:90)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleSync(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:65)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:145)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.process(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:83)
        at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorSupport.process(AsyncProcessorSupport.java:41)
        at org.apache.camel.jta.TransactionErrorHandler.processByErrorHandler(TransactionErrorHandler.java:233)
        at org.apache.camel.jta.TransactionErrorHandler$1.run(TransactionErrorHandler.java:196)
        at org.apache.camel.quarkus.component.jta.TransactionalJtaTransactionPolicy.runWithTransaction(TransactionalJtaTransactionPolicy.java:48)
        at org.apache.camel.quarkus.component.jta.RequiredJtaTransactionPolicy.run(RequiredJtaTransactionPolicy.java:26)
        at org.apache.camel.jta.TransactionErrorHandler.doInTransactionTemplate(TransactionErrorHandler.java:186)
        at org.apache.camel.jta.TransactionErrorHandler.processInTransaction(TransactionErrorHandler.java:137)
        at org.apache.camel.jta.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:101)
        at org.apache.camel.jta.TransactionErrorHandler.process(TransactionErrorHandler.java:110)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$SimpleTask.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:395)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:60)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:147)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:312)
        at org.apache.camel.component.netty.handlers.ServerChannelHandler.processAsynchronously(ServerChannelHandler.java:142)
        at org.apache.camel.component.netty.handlers.ServerChannelHandler.channelRead0(ServerChannelHandler.java:113)
        at org.apache.camel.component.netty.http.handlers.HttpServerChannelHandler.channelRead0(HttpServerChannelHandler.java:221)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
        at org.apache.camel.component.netty.http.handlers.HttpServerMultiplexChannelHandler.channelRead0(HttpServerMultiplexChannelHandler.java:162)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$600(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:61)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$7.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:370)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor.run(DefaultEventExecutor.java:66)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints". ClientConnectionId:938c1bcb-8e88-46d9-9776-379716c39369
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2892)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1881)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2452)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2103)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1950)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1162)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:735)
        at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:200)
        at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:452)
        at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:434)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at io.agroal.pool.util.PriorityScheduledExecutor.beforeExecute(PriorityScheduledExecutor.java:65)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1126)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:349)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:292)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:287)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:421)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:182)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:171)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1418)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1324)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:411)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1799)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkAlgorithmConstraints(SSLContextImpl.java:1681)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkAdditionalTrust(SSLContextImpl.java:1606)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:1550)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Algorithm constraints check failed on keysize limits: RSA 1024 bit key used with certificate: CN=SSL_Self_Signed_Fallback
        at java.base/sun.security.util.DisabledAlgorithmConstraints$KeySizeConstraint.permits(DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.java:893)
        at java.base/sun.security.util.DisabledAlgorithmConstraints$Constraints.permits(DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.java:511)
        at java.base/sun.security.util.DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.permits(DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.java:251)
        at java.base/sun.security.util.DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.permits(DisabledAlgorithmConstraints.java:197)
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.AlgorithmChecker.check(AlgorithmChecker.java:292)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkAlgorithmConstraints(SSLContextImpl.java:1677)
        ... 28 more
```

Comment: SQL Servers are typically configured with a self-signed certificate at install time. Add `;trustServerCertificate=true`. Or a bit of a click-fest, but if you have remote access to the SQL Server you can go to SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for MSSQLSERVER (or whatever the instance name) > right-click Properties > Certificate tab > View... button > Details tab > Copy to file... button. In the Certificate Export Wizard that opens choose one of the X.509 .cer formats, save the public key to a file and import that file into your Java trust store.

Comment: i tried with ;trustServerCertificate=true and  ;integratedSecurity=true;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true  both does not help, same errror dont know why

Comment: the problem is solved ,it is due to openjdk 11doesnot allow RSA Keysize 1024, it requires RSA size at least 2048 by default . btw my another question, since MSSQL Server uses self sign certifciate, it has no default trusted root CA at JVM's truststore. i assume i need manullay import self-sign certifcate into jvm truststore to make it work, but i did not do this. it works why?

Comment: @stewchicken How do you resolved the problem? Is there an option for the jdk11?

Comment: i used oraclejdk12 as workaround, oraclejdk tolerates rsa keyzsie as 1024.